# Powershell - Copy backup folder from single Source to Multiple-Destinations

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

I have a t-sql query that returns a collections of paths.

I need, given a source folder/path, to copy such folder, and its files to the destinations.

My question is, given this query :

```sql
SELECT [MasterDBLocation] FROM [DBBackupMasterLocation]
```

Results :

```
\\BASELINES17.newgen.corp\Baselines
\\BASELINES23.newgen.corp\Baselines
```

how do I store the results of that query in powershell, and then loop through all paths, to copy the folder from source to all paths returned by that query?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you running the query in powershell?

Comment: Connecting to the instance using .net in powershell (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll)

Comment: I have the dataset(datatable) from SQL. I need to write PS to loop through that copying the folder and its files from source to all the paths returned by the query

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$Data = SQL_Query "SELECT MasterDBLocation FROM DBBackupMasterLocation"

Export-Csv -InputObject $Data -Path "C:\Main\Data.csv"

Copy-Item -Path "C:\Main\Data.csv" -Destination "D:\Backuo\Data.csv"
```